# Make one column from two columns in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have displayed data in two columns but now I require to convert them in one column, unfortunately I'm not able to do that.
I have the following fields like name, image, short description, and when I tried to convert it become like name,name image,image short desc,short desc.
My code is as follow:

> "Keep in mind: I want to display row1,row2,row3,row4 as one column and below it
>   row5,row6,row7,row8 as second column" **it is displayed olny when screen has pixel less than 640 otherwise(morethen 640px) below code is working perfact**

```
  <?php
        $counter = 0;
        $row1  = array();
        $row2  = array();
        $row3 = array();
        $row4 = array();
        $row5 = array();
        $row6 = array();
        $row7  = array();
        $row8  = array();
        if ( have_posts() ) :
            $add_clear = 1;
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                $post_tagline = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'dbt_post-tagline', true );
               $short_desc = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'dbt_short_desc', true );
               $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src(get_post_thumbnail_id(get_the_ID()),'full');

                if($counter %2 == 0) {
                    $row1[] = '<td valign="top" class="thumb">
                        <h3>
                            <div>
                                ' . get_the_title(get_the_ID()) .'
                            </div>
                        </h3>
                    </td>';
                    $row2[] = '<td valign="top" >
                        <p>
                                <a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '" rel="bookmark">
                                <img src="' . $image_attributes[0] . '" />
                        </p>
                  </td>';

                   $row3[] = '<td valign="top" class="excerpt-part">
                        <p>' . $short_desc . '...</p>
                   </td>';
                    $row4[] = '<td valign="top" class="thumb">
                       <p>
                            <a href="' . get_the_permalink(get_the_ID()) . '"> VIEW MORE </a>
                        </p>
                   </td>';

                }
                else {

                    $row5[] = '<td valign="top" class="thumb">
                        <h3>
                            <div>
                                ' . get_the_title(get_the_ID()) .'
                            </div>
                        </h3>
                    </td>';
                    echo '<div class="thumbnail">';*/
                    $row6[] = '<td valign="top">
                        <p>
                                <a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '" rel="bookmark">
                                <img src="' . $image_attributes[0] . '" />
                        </p>
                   </td>';
                    $row7[] = '<td valign="top" class="excerpt-part">
                         <p>' . $short_desc . '...</p>
                   </td>';
                    $row8[] = '<td valign="top" class="thumb">
                       <p>
                            <a href="' . get_the_permalink(get_the_ID()) . '"> VIEW MORE </a>
                        </p>
                   </td>';

                }
                $counter++;

                if ( ($add_clear % 2 ) == 0 )
                $add_clear++;
            endwhile; // end of the loop.

       ?>
        <table class="common-tbl-custom-style">
        <?php
            for($i= 0; $i< $counter; $i++) { ?>
        <tr>
            <?php echo (isset($row1[$i]) && $row1[$i]) ? $row1[$i]: "";  ?>
            <?php echo (isset($row5[$i]) && $row5[$i]) ? $row5[$i]: "";  ?>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <?php echo (isset($row2[$i]) && $row2[$i]) ? $row2[$i]: "";  ?>
            <?php echo (isset($row6[$i]) && $row6[$i]) ? $row6[$i]: "";  ?>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <?php echo (isset($row3[$i]) && $row3[$i]) ? $row3[$i]: "";  ?>
            <?php echo (isset($row7[$i]) && $row7[$i]) ? $row7[$i]: "";  ?>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <?php echo (isset($row4[$i]) && $row4[$i]) ? $row4[$i]: "";  ?>
            <?php echo (isset($row8[$i]) && $row8[$i]) ? $row8[$i]: "";  ?>
        </tr>

        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: And what is exactly the problem? What have you tried? Because it seems to me you just need tot echo `$row[1]` to `$row[4]` in the same `<tr>` and then in the next `<tr>` you have  `$row[5]` to `$row[8]`. So you have 2  `<tr>`  tags instead of 4.

Comment: yest but it displayed when pixel is less than 640 so want to display in single column less than or equal to 640 pixel

Comment: it is good upto 640 pixel but after it i want to display only one column and thanks very much for your help :)

Comment: This is more a problem of html/css then. And not of php.

Comment: ok thanks a lot for your help